# Babel with french option mess with SageTeX and `\addplot`

Tags: pgfplots, babel, python, sagetex

I'm trying to easily plot with `pgfplots` some python outputs. I really don't like the `matplotlib2tikz` default behavior, which is to copy the default parameters of matplotlib, and I can't find how to override it. I would like to have my basic axis, so all the custom config would be in my `\pgfplotsset{}`.

So I did some basic functions in python, and I call them with `sagetex`. I like this package because I can load all the imports and access to the results anywhere in the document. It almost works perfectly, except with `babel` and the french options. Here is a MWE :

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}

\usepackage[french]{babel}     %<--- Any one of these make it fail
%\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}   %<--- This 
%\usepackage[francais]{babel}  %<--- This 

%\usepackage[english]{babel}   %<--- But this one is okay.

\begin{document}
%Import python function
\begin{sagesilent}

############## python code
def addplot_coordinates(*args, **kwargs):
  if len(kwargs) is 0:
    code = [r'\addplot coordinates {']
  else:
    code = [r'\addplot[']
    for key, value in kwargs.items():
      code.append('  {0} = {1},'.format(key, str(value)))
    code.append('  ] coordinates {')
  while True:
    try:
      value = [str(x.pop()) for x in args]
    except IndexError:
      break
    line = '    ( ' + ' , '.join(value) + ' )'
    code.append(line)
  code.append(r'} ;')
  return '\n'.join(code)

# Print a test in standard output during sage compilation to be sure it works
print(addplot_coordinates([1,3,2,4], [2,5,3,2], draw='black'))
############## end of python code

\end{sagesilent}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}

      % This plot works fine
      \addplot[
        draw = blue,
        ] coordinates {
          ( 4 , 2 ) ( 2 , 1 ) ( 3 , 2 ) ( 1 , 1 )
      } ;

      % This plots fails
      \sagestr{addplot_coordinates([1,2,3,4], [4,3,4,3], draw='red')}

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Used without `babel`, or with the english option, it compiles (pdflatex, sage, pdflatex). But with one of the french options, I have this error during the 2nd pdflatex compilation:

```
Runaway argument?
 ;{}{}{}\null \fi \@safe@activesfalse \end {NoHyper}\@ifundefined {r@\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \pgfplots@addplotimpl@coordinates.
<inserted text> 
              \par 
<*> TestBug.tex
```

I have found something in the [SageTex manual](http://w.astro.berkeley.edu/~domagalski/latex/sagetexpackage.pdf) about the `NoHyper` environment (p. 22), saying that there have been a problem, but I don't understand it as if I should protect my code with something.

It may worth mentioning that everything is fine as long as :

- I do not invoke a `\addplot` command
- I use an other `babel` option

Does any one have a clue on what might happen ?
Plus, I'm totally fine with coding this pgf-python interface, since it will give me a lot of control on what I do, but feel free to advise me a better way.

Thank you for you time !

Comment: see if you add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` before or after`\usepackage{pgfplots}` helps to resolve your problem.

Comment: As you suggested, I added \usetikzlibrary{babel} after \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13} and the errors disappeared.

Comment: Yes, it does solve the problem. Thank you.
So I tried to understand why, and it was simply the `;`. A `\shorthandoff{;}` removes the compilation fail. Should I add an answer ?

Comment: of course you should :), actually, you already done :-) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, it was just a simple `babel`-`tikz` problem.

As suggested in the comments by Zarko, adding:

```
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
```

solves the problem.